# Tails Live CD checksum

Tags: tails

If you made USB stick in Linux with the official method, then you first insert the USB stick of Tails Live OS, then run "Disks" from the menu, you can see the USB stick, click it and at the right side of window shows the paragraph about the volumes, click the "play" icon under the "TAILS 1.0.1" partition, then you browse the USB stick by your file browser manager, you can find those files:

```
aa7e6d827404015f66680fd7c8a1675f  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/boot.cat
a4782a55055ebd999b0d83b47fb1e6e3  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/exithelp.cfg
40faedcc180edcaabd217216bea67c6b  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f1.txt
e6381257dc0acbed8a371abedfe57bdd  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f2.txt
2cb10d49a1a826dcd913fec5709db16b  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f3.txt
62273f2c8233e4415da83e9bb465e00f  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f4.txt
9b5a4384308490355bf8510de43bde03  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f5.txt
b4d488f1918b267a356132fbf0bc8569  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f6.txt
2085c54656f8b51736f609336aec9e25  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f7.txt
0f57ef3a28de79ae37055b564ee73421  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f8.txt
df16347faf6dd5eff29970f7bfb6860f  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f9.txt
c9b8368b667fe30e7f9663f81900d27d  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/f10.txt
f7acb783bb996aa0c361773269491b87  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/ifcpu64.c32
d772fae51e8a50005f259dbe79818572  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/isolinux.bin
a00d53e8bdb59b2e34d80fa1be86fc16  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/isolinux.cfg
8ec15b1d41dbc9b30a161f595eecb20d  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/live.cfg
baaa460483b2309d6b698e5f9eb5f35c  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/live486.cfg
3eafe584d27211bf29d3708953fd683e  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/liveamd64.cfg
79843eda78b40b89641d6fc9dcc2a6f3  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/menu.cfg
c74ec1dfe4a9e72d9e40fba16b385921  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/prompt.cfg
baea618231e3fe90a50f2b8c5215dcc3  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/splash.png
f8900fcc2f81364be02cbca165d4c74f  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/stdmenu.cfg
d8a960e359dc340d09f3713e93e00684  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/tails.cfg
5a25bff3b63f5fa50b31c1f21c9981f8  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/isolinux/vesamenu.c32

465b0c63b3403decb53c5a4e23e2a1c4  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/live/Tails.module
f88ffb54f91d9de40a9380ee47e18803  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/live/filesystem.squashfs
3cb04357546d93897a0d64e30f6af199  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/live/filesystem.packages
f0bfa94e1d7be45bd8aa42be9bb17fe4  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/live/initrd.img
df752aec23e730ad0a4f7a0371e45b3a  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/live/initrd2.img
5fec87fbcb392c400873a148818ba9d2  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/live/vmlinuz
94d22a17603113a22a2b5c2f56712b76  /run/media/zilo/TAILS 1.0.1 - 20140608/live/vmlinuz2
```

If you make the iso in Windows, you just need to open the directory in USB stick.

So do you have the same MD5Checksum?
My downloaded ISO file are different with the checksum, what's the files inside? Is that safe to use this USB stick made by this ISO?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but AFAIK it's far more common place to check the hash of .iso files rather than their unpacked contents.
How to do that is explained here https://tails.boum.org/download/index.en.html#verify

Answer (score 2):

As @user194 says, it is difficult to know quite what you are asking. But assuming that you are asking about the unpacked files versus the iso, then I think it is reasonable to say:

1. If you verified the identity of the ISO using the methods described
   on the Tails site, then the ISO is safe (within the bounds of safety
   of anything cryptographic!).
2. If you created the USB bootstick using the methods described on the
   Tails site, and assuming that your machine is not already grossly
   compromised, then the USB version is safe to use.
3. There is absolutely no reason to expect that the concatenation of
   all the individual files unpacked from the ISO would give the same
   MD5 hash as the ISO itself. In fact, if they did, it is then that
   one would begin to suspect that something was seriously wrong!